# Unable to protect payload as Error Response

Tags: rest, api, mule, mule-component

I am doing Get Rest Call using mule HTTP components.It returns expected response most of the time. But some times, i am getting the response (400) like this:-

{
   "error":"invalid_json",
   "description":"Payload is not of type java.io.InputStream, java.lang.String not byte array. Unable to protect payload."
}

From Soap UI it's returning expected json. I am wondering what is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Set `Content-Type` property before calling `http` component.

`<set-property propertyName="content-type" value="application/json" doc:name="set-content-type-property"/>`

Comment: Tried this options. Got Timeout response . I checked the difference between success and invalid response call. It looks like Mule Message MIME type is going as Application/json for all invalid json response. Changing the MIME Type to */* worked for this call.

Comment: Service timing out is independent of setting correct mime type